# Error during the executing a file with GMP library

Tags: c, gmp

I have installed gmp library many times and run several programs. Every time I run my first program after 'successful' compilation, i hit the following error.

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: 
libgmp.so.10: cannot open shared object  file: No such file or directory
```

After immense amount of looking over the net, I was not able to resolve this issue correctly.

PS: One suggestion in one of the forums was to create the link to the library file in i think /usr/lib. But it was condemned badly in the same thread.

Eventually I want my code to run. A quick solution for this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try `ldd ./a.out` which should show you where the system is looking for the lib. But yeah, it means that it's not correctly installed, or that the search path for this lib is not good.

So the symlink may be a good idea. How did you installed GMP on your computer? apt-like or compilation?

Comment: I followed the traditional make,make install